# Select text from descending elements and the element itself

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to select text from descending elements and the element itself. What xpath selector can do this and how can I combine all text parts?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me at all. Can you give some further context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `//text()`.

Taken [from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp):

> // - Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are

Example:

```
$ scrapy shell
In [1]: data = """
   ...: <div> root text
   ...: <div> level 2 text </div>
   ...: <div> level 2 text2 </div>
   ...: </div>
   ...: """
In [2]: from scrapy import Selector
In [3]: sel = Selector(text=data)
In [4]: sel.xpath("//div//text()").extract()
Out[4]: [u' root text\n', u' level 2 text ', u'\n', u' level 2 text2 ', u'\n']
```